Vauxhall/Opel Corsa E 2017 Grinding noise when accelerating [SOLVED]
I have a Corsa E 2017 manual transmission which was a flood car but I rebuilt it and noticed grinding/rattling(ish)/shuddering noise when accelerating normally from a full stop. The noise from inside the cabin I can describe is kind of a metal rough object scraping the undercarriage of the car. the scraping noise are there for a second or so and it is gone once the car is moving. Also this noise occurs when trying to accelerate quickly in lower gears. Didn't notice in higher gears particularly from 3rd gear. I have been looking at this issue online and people there were suggesting several possible areas to look at/investigate . I looked at the following areas.

CV boot joints/ Driveshafts: Although I noticed very very tiny play when I tried to grab both the drive shaft from underneath when I tried to force some play into it, both the driveshafts were in excellent condition, I thoroughly checked the boots for any puncture/play and the both driveshaft appeared to be in good condition so I assumed it wasnt the issue. I also did another test which supports my conclusion of driveshaft not being the culprit of that noise which Ive written about it further down this text area.
Engine Mount/Transmission Mounts: I looked at all the engine/transmission mounting points/brackets and bolts to see if they were loose, and they were all very tight. I did not loosen them to check if the mounting bolts were bent or broke and I so far didn't notice any noisy play that could contribute to noise. Although in the video you can see in the video the engine moves quite far on the transmission mount but not sure.
Gearbox itself: This one I am not sure how to confirm that the gearbox is the issue apart from a general idea that the noise seems to be coming from the transmission half of the side or more towards the passenger side.

The test:
I discovered that I could reproduce the noise by putting the car in maximum parking brake and chocking all four wheels and putting the car to its maximum biting point. I removed the battery tray/compartment so that the engine mounts could be seen when trying to run the test. This concluded me its not drive shafts because its not moving at all.
I have asked my wife to record and she has done her best to record the noise which I am attaching a video at this post. I put the car several times at its biting point so that it could reproduce the noise a few times which you can see in the video when the engine is moving due the clutch being engaged and that's when you will hear that shuddering noise.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions suspicions or any idea of further testing to confirm the culprit component.
Also please do let me know if the video is not clear and I shall do my best again to record more clearly.
Thank you in advance.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JoWG09VguIEqPhoU0vj-1z9peAP6PWhb/view

Similar to other issues with the grinding noise on acceleration. The culprit on mine was also the transmission mount that sits underneath the transmission and connects the transmission bracket to the car's frame. The transmission bracket has a protrusion at the tip that just about touched the metal brace that goes across the subframe of the car due to the rubber padding cracking and wearing out in the mount which allowed too much movement which was causing that horrible noise.

Once I replaced the part , I tried an aggressive acceleration and there was no noise after that.
